# An illegal reflective access operation has occurred, Java telegram bot

Tags: java, gradle, guice, telegram

I've been using this [library](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots) to try and run a Telegram bot using Java.
I setup the project using Gradle in order to use the dependencies.

My project hierarchy is as follows:

```
.gradle
build
gradle
src
 -main
  -java
   -Main.java
   -MyAmazingBot.java
build.gradle
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

This is the [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) I used to setup up Gradle. I used the Gradle Wrapper to get my build running.

However, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/addis/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.inject/guice/4.1.0/eeb69005da379a10071aa4948c48d89250febb07/guice-4.1.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Yet the bot runs fine (it echoes my messages back).

1) Should this message be a cause for concern?

2) Is it possible to run the jar file using `java -jar`? I get a message `no main manifest attribute, in .\build\libs\fsc2.jar`

3) Is it possible to run `./gradlew run` without using Gradle's wrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently due to an incompatibility between Guice  and Java 9.  See issue link below.

There is no fix just yet.  However

- this is just a warning, and
- there is a workaround in the issue comments to turn off all of these illegal access warnings.

Issue link:

- https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1133

I don't think Gradle is actually at fault here.  It seems that the problem is in Telegram / Guice / Cglib.

Comment: The warning seems to be Guice/CGLIB, not Gradle.

Comment: Yea.  I found the wrong issue.  A fresh search found the right one.